# When importing a wallet from private key or seed phrase, how do you guess the correct address format?

Tags: wallet, wallet-recovery

I am building a bitcoin wallet. I can derive addresses using the derivation paths. How do I determine the derivation path for the seed when importing it?

Comment: or do i just do a wallet address lookup based on the supported derivation paths and keep searching for about 20 address if it has any transactions on the blockchain ?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I determine the derivation path for the seed when importing it?

I don't think you can determine the derivation path from the seed phrase, you have to ask the user to choose one from a list or input it if not listed. You can build in a list of derivation paths for popular wallets, the user then has to know the name, and maybe version number, of the wallet that produced the seed they are importing.

> or do i just do a wallet address lookup based on the supported derivation paths and keep searching for about 20 address if it has any transactions on the blockchain ?

That would work in many cases. It assumes you have access to a full copy of the blockchain indexed by all addresses with non-zero balance. It needn't be local but a non-local source might make your seed-importation take a long time.